# Add column with current date and time to Polars DataFrame

Tags: python, python-polars

How can I add a column to a Polars DataFrame with current date and time as value on every row?

With Pandas, I would do something like this:

```py
df["date"] = pd.Timestamp.today()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT: Better answer from @jqurious:

```py
df.with_columns(date = datetime.now())
```

#### My original solution:

Use `pl.lit()` and Python's `datetime` to create a literal of the current date:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame( ... )
df.with_columns(pl.lit(datetime.now()).dt.datetime().alias("date"))
```

Comment: `df.with_columns(date = datetime.now())`